# Getting error 415 - Unsupported media Type in fetch api

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch

**Following curl request is working and it's generating token. But when I use it as fetch API, I'm getting 415 error - Unsupported media type.**

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -u "Secret_ID:Secret_Key" -d "grant_type=password&username=mahesh@gmail.com&password=Welcome1234&scope=https://si01-test.prod.com/bca/api" "https://identity.com/oauth2/v1/token"
```

**I'm using fetch API like this:**

```
let username = 'Secret_ID';
let password = 'Secret_Key';
let formdata = new FormData();
let headers = new Headers();

formdata.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
formdata.append('grant_type','password');
formdata.append('username','mahesh@gmail.com');
formdata.append('password','Welcome1234');
formdata.append('scope','https://si01-test.prod.com/bca/api');

headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic VGVzdF9zaTAxX0FQUElEOjNkZGI4MmYxLWI5OTktNDlhMy1hMmM5LWQ1OGMyOTU2ODg4Yg=='); // encoded username and password
fetch('https://identity.com/oauth2/v1/token', {
 method: 'POST',
 headers: headers,
 body: formdata
}).then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
 console.log(responseJson);

 this.setState({
    data: responseJson
 })
  })
   .catch((error) => {
 console.error(error);
   });
```

**What's wrong here? Any suggestion will be appreciable..**

Comment: Try adding 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to the header not to the formdata.

Comment: @Prabhjot, tried that as well.

Comment: But in the code you have appended it to formdata. Also try not appending the header instead write the header in fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I mentioned, Request is working fine in CuRL / Postman and it makes my life easier.

If you you have curl command and its working fine then you can just import that command directly in postman and it will work fine.
[image]

Now if your request is working fine in postman, then you can just copy code of it in any language that is given in Postman.

[image]

Comment: I spend so much time trying to resolve, you really save me man, thank youuu!